# Allow upvoting your own post/question if you click 1000 times

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sometimes I truly believe that my answer is superior. Why not introduce a 1000 click test of the faith?

Not sure if captcha would be needed.

Answer (score 11):

If your answer is truly superior and one upvote will actually make a difference then your answer is effectively voted the same as the competing answers anyway.

If your answer is truly superior and you can't get anyone to vote on it then maybe it's not that superior...

You clicking 1,000 times doesn't prove anything.

If your answer is superior then over time it'll become the most highly voted. If it's not then it won't. By posting you're casting your work onto the winds of fate. Let them do their work and if they don't help you then, well, that's life quite frankly.

Answer (score 7):

No.

Because [Dunning–Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), if nothing else.

Comment: If others however say you're the best on their website, that's no longer an issue, right?

Comment: @Bart you're the best on their website